# What's the relationship between PassportJS & Auth0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, auth0

I thought it was `PassportJS` vs. `Auth0`. Now I just discovered that there is a PassportJS strategy called [passport-auth0](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-auth0/) - which confuses me. Could somebody explain this to me?

[Here](https://github.com/auth0/passport-auth0) it says that Passport `is authentication middleware for Node.js that can be unobtrusively dropped into any Express-based web application.` - I'm not sure I understand this?

Answer (score 7):

PassportJS is a javascript framework/middleware designed to assist with authentication/authorization mechanisms in your platform. One of the ways you can use it is along with an oAuth flow. An other would be to use it only with JWTs. A third way could be to use it alongside simple "cookies".

Think of it a little bit like saying Visual Studio vs C#.
You can write c# with visual studio.
And you can write vb with visual studio.

Similarly you can either use oAuth,JWTs,simple cookies, or anything else that you want to use as authentication/authorization for your application, and passportJS can make it easier for you by handling some stuff, regardless of which "strategy" you choose to implement for your app.

Comment: As as I remember passportjs was made by an Argentinian kid who went on to make auth0 but could be wrong. I remember when auth0 was just an indie Node project